# ODBC RDB 64-bit drivers

Tags: 64-bit, oracle-rdb

I need to get a 64-bit ODBC driver for a Windows 2008 r2 server to connect to an RDB database (v7.2).  I downloaded the Oracle ODBC Driver for RDB 3.3.2.0 but I can't get it to connect.

Has anyone used this? Should I be able to connect using this?
The error I get at the moment is

> recv() unexpected close ret ) err#0 unknown

I don't see any tnsnames or listener file with this driver are they required?

Comment: I've used almost the exact same setup as you describe and it works for me. Have you been able to test a connection using the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error before and it normally relates to a server side SQL Services error.

Try restarting SQL Services on your VMS box.

There are no tnsnames files etc - you should be able to just setup a 64bit ODBC connection via control panel -> odbc as normal.

In practice though I have found the 64 bit ODBC drivers to be buggy, and have experienced much pain using them. Ditto for the .NET drivers. 
(32bit has worked fine though. )

I remember seeing a roadmap from Oracle which stated that they were releasing a new (written from ground up) set of ODBC drivers for RDB 64 bit, so perhaps they do have an underlying issue. I just search for the link, but couldn't find it. If I do come across it again I'll make sure I add it here.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ODBC Driver for RDB is only for Oracle RDB Database.